# Card Container not showing up properly in grid layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to create a layout using Scroll View and Grid Layout. I am using 2 columns and 3 rows.

The problem is one column shows up okay but the 2nd column is nowhere to be found, as it doesn't appear on the app.

Images for reference:

[image]

[image]

Code is as under:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".bikeList">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:rowCount="3">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeImage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/superpower_sp110_cheetah" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Super Power SP 110 Cheetah"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeImage"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeType"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeName"
                            android:text="Bike type"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeTypeAnswer"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Manual"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeType"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/condition"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeTypeAnswer"
                            android:text="Condition"/>
                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/conditionRating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:rating="4"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeImage2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/superpower_sp110_cheetah" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeName2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Super Power SP 110 Cheetah"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeImage2"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeType2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeName2"
                            android:text="Bike type"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeTypeAnswer2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Manual"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeType2"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/condition2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeTypeAnswer2"
                            android:text="Condition"/>
                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/conditionRating2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition2"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:rating="4"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeImage3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/superpower_sp110_cheetah" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeName3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Super Power SP 110 Cheetah"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeImage3"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeType3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeName3"
                            android:text="Bike type"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeTypeAnswer3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Manual"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeType3"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/condition3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeTypeAnswer3"
                            android:text="Condition"/>
                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/conditionRating3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition3"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:rating="4"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_rowWeight="1">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeImage4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/superpower_sp110_cheetah" />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeName4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Super Power SP 110 Cheetah"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeImage4"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeType4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeName4"
                            android:text="Bike type"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bikeTypeAnswer4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Manual"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeType4"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/condition4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/bikeTypeAnswer4"
                            android:text="Condition"/>
                        <RatingBar
                            android:id="@+id/conditionRating4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/condition4"
                            android:numStars="5"
                            android:rating="4"
                            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cardview displays Items in a single column as default, try to define your own custom adapter class in your activity script...